# Make a specific reviewer review the code on gerrit

Tags: ssh, gerrit

I am running gerrit on dockers. I have a user who created a project on gerrit. I have created a user called user1, added the user to the list of reviewers for the project created. I have done all this on the same host machine. I created the user using the following command,

```
cat  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 29446 host_ip gerrit create-account --group "'Administrators'" --ssh-key - user1
```

I added user1 to the list of reviewers for the project demo using the command,

```
ssh -p 29446 host_ip gerrit set-reviewers \
 --project demo \
  -a user1 \
  commit_id
```

Now I want to review code through the user user1. When I try the following command to review the code, it reviews code as the creator of the project. How do I review the code as user1?

```
ssh -p 29446 host_ip gerrit review --code-review +2 commit_id
```

Comment: `ssh -p 29446 user1@host_ip gerrit review --code-review +2 commit_id` ?

Comment: It works:) Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify user for SSH connection, i.e.:

```
ssh -p 29446 user1@host_ip gerrit review --code-review +2 commit_id
```